# paypal cURL command using certificates

Tags: paypal

I'm switching from using signatures to using certificates for authentication with PayPal for their Express Checkout API. Signatures worked great but I'm unable to get certificates to work. The command I'm using is:

> `curl -v -E /private/cert_key_pem.txt:PASSWORD -d "METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=121&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=10.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.230.132%2FLicense%3FTRANSACTION%3D1%26CANCEL%3D1&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.230.132%2FLicense%3FTRANSACTION%3D1" https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`

I've tried a number of variations on the above and quadruple checked the password and pem file but I always get the response:

> `L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Authentication/Authorization Failed&L_LONGMESSAGE0=You do not have permissions to make this API call&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error`

Can anyone provide an example curl command that should work? Is there anything that I need to turn on or enable to get this to work with the PayPal sandbox?

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: I was still using the signature endpoint instead of the certificate endpoint. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make certain you are using the Certificate from your Sandbox Account. 
Also Include:

```
&USER=<Certificate API-Username> 
&PWD=<Certificate API-Password>
```

You may need to remove the Signature from the Sandbox Account and request the API Certificate from sandbox.paypal.com.
[Generating an API Certificate](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/#generate-the-certificate-set)

You cannot have an API Signature and an API Certificate on the same Sandbox or Live PayPal Account.

[image]